# how to set a text length for org agenda items?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Because the items in my agenda come directly from the header lines of org items, they can get long or uneven. I see this especially when I am bringing the items in from an email subject line. How can I set a length that will be respected so that all lines are even, truncating or padding as necessary?

Comment: I don't know of a simple way to do that: you could add a function that truncates the text of each entry e.g. in `org-agenda-finalize-hook` but I don't think it's going to be simple. I looked a bit into the `org-agenda` sources and did not see anything promising.

Comment: Shoot. I had hoped that was never the case with Emacs, but for something as HUGE as Org, apparently the complexity does hide some limits